# JXL Get Cell Address

Tags: excel, jxl

I am using the Java [jxl](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) api v2.6.16 to generate Excel Spread Sheet. Like the above title puts it, how do get an address of a Cell or More specifically Writable cell that I am writing to if all I have is the cell's column and row? Or do I have to write an algorithm which can generate that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. Hope this help. You can use it in this way:

`cellAddress(cell.getRow() + 1, cell.getColumn())` if cell is defined like `Cell cell = someCell;`

```java
private String cellAddress(Integer rowNumber, Integer colNumber){
    return "$"+columnName(colNumber)+"$"+rowNumber;
}

private String columName(Integer colNumber) {

    Base columns = new Base(colNumber,26);
    columns.transform();
    return columns.getResult();
}

class Base {
    String[] colNames = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z".split(",");
    String equalTo;
    int position;
    int number;
    int base;
    int[] digits;
    int[] auxiliar;

    public Base(int n, int b) {
        position = 0;
        equalTo = "";
        base = b;
        number = n;
        digits = new int[1];
    }

    public void transform() {
        if (number < base) {
            digits[position] = number;
            size();
        } else {
            digits[position] = number % base;
            size();
            position++;
            number = number / base;
            transform();
        }
    }

    public String getResult() {
        for (int j = digits.length - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
            equalTo += colNames[j>0?digits[j]-1:digits[j]];
        }
        return equalTo;
    }

    private void size() {
        auxiliar = digits;
        digits = new int[auxiliar.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(auxiliar, 0, digits, 0, auxiliar.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: method to get cellAddress is not implemented yet in jxl

Answer (score 0):

the Address is made up of the Column and Row.

In **A1 Notation** it is written like: `Range("A1")` where the column 1 is rtepresented by the letter "A" and the row is 1

In **R1C1 Notation** it would be written like this: `R1C1` where the column is 1 and the row is 1

They would be used like this:

```
Cells(1,1).font.bold=true ' row 1, column 1
range("A1").font.bold=true
```

to get the address from a Reference, retrieve the *Address* property of the **Cells** or **Range** object as below:

```
sAddress=cells(1,1).address
```

which would return **A$1$**

and in JXL, `String rangeAddress = range.getAddress();`

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I wanted. In fact I wanted the reverse. For example, how do I get a Cell Address of `Cell(1,1)`for instance. Either way I did not find the solution, I had to write an algorithm to find the address.

Comment: so you wanted `cells(1,1).address` ? That returns **$A$1**

Comment: @DaveAgaba I have modified my answer to give you what you wanted.

Comment: @DaveAgaba no need for an algorythm

Comment: this version does not have that option of address. Check documentation [link](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/index.html)

Comment: It's part of the MS Excel Object Model...so it does have the property. You just have to write code to retrieve that property

Comment: Can't you use `String rangeAddress = range.getAddress();` ?

Comment: Please take a look at the JavDoc link I attached on my previous comment. Clearly that method was not included in the version that I am using. There isn't any `getAddress()` method. But its ok, I got away around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the column by it's alpha index by using one of the methods below. he simple method just casts an integer to a ASCII character. The second method allows the use of a custom alphabet.

## Simple Method

```
public class LookupUtil {
    public static String cellAddress(int row, int col) {
        return String.format("$%s$%d", columnName(col), row);
    }

    public static String columnName(int index) {
        int div = index + 1;
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        int mod = 0;

        while (div > 0) {
            mod = (div - 1) % 26;
            result.insert(0, (char) (65 + mod));
            div = (int) ((div - mod) / 26);
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

## Advanced Method

```
public class LookupUtil {
    private static final char[] ALPHA = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

    public static String cellAddress(int row, int col) {
        return String.format("$%s$%d", columnName(col, ALPHA), row);
    }

    public static String columnName(int index, char[] alphabet) {
        int div = index + 1;
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        int mod = 0;

        while (div > 0) {
            mod = (div - 1) % alphabet.length;
            result.insert(0, alphabet[mod]);
            div = (int) ((div - mod) / alphabet.length);
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```